# saving a animated plot from vscode to my computer

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, data-visualization

I have created an animated plot on vscode and I would like to save it to my desktop.
currently I have:

```
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func=animation_frame, interval=10)
plt.show()
writer = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=15, metadata=dict(artist='Me'), bitrate=1800)
animation.save("movie.mp4", writer=writer)
```

But it returns error:

```
AttributeError: 'FuncAnimation' object has no attribute 'FFmpegWriter'
```

I did pip install FFmpeg successfully.

I also tried this one:

```
animation.save("movie.mp4")
```

But it also returns an error:

```
ValueError: unknown file extension: .mp4
```

Any idea how to fix either of this situation? Or how to download the animated plot from vscode please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `animation.save("movie.mp4",writer='ffmpeg')`If so, can't I save it?

Answer (score 0):

For saving the drawn animation, I use the following code to automatically save the drawing as a gif:

> ```
>  ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=200, repeat_delay=1000)
>  plt.show()
>  ani.save("test1.gif", writer='pillow') #The default is in the project, you can also specify the path.
> ```

Complete code:

> ```
> import matplotlib.animation as animation
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> ims = []
> fig = plt.figure()
> for i in range(1,10):
>     im = plt.scatter(1,1).findobj()
>     ims.append(im)
> ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=200, repeat_delay=1000)
> plt.show()
> ani.save("test1.gif", writer='pillow')
> ```

Result:

[image]

Comment: hmmm, for some reason the gif is not generated. :(

Comment: @조혜연 Could you provide us with a detailed description so that we can help you better.